# How to handle huge amounts of data for concurrent execution (NSOperationQueue or Blocks)

Tags: ios, concurrency, queue, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue

I have to handle huge amounts of data at once. Therefor I use Blocks or NSOperationQueue.
Everything works fine until the amount of data to process exceeds the memory limit.
This results in a instant app crash.

The reason for that is that the data packages I have to process are approx. 100KB big.
After more than 300-400 of this operations are queued in the queue the memory limit is exceeded.

Now I would like to know how you guys handle similar problems?
BTW: I did not find a no way to limit the queue size unless I add synchronized tasks which will cause the stack to be completed before returning.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the nature of these "data packages"? Do you need to queue all 300-400 of them or could you queue just a few (or one) and then upon completion of each, add another to the queue? And are you staging the data for all of these packages, or does each process retrieve and process the particular package of data? Bottom line, your question is awfully cryptic. The more specific you can be (esp code samples), the more helpful we can probably be.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I was wondering if there is any pattern I could use to solve such problems. Of course I could synchronize the process which would solve the problem. But I would rather like to have more control like I have in Java when I am using the ThreadPoolExecutor. But I don't see a comparable concept in iOS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ThreadPoolExecutor so it's hard for me to answer that. I don't know what functionality ThreadPoolExecutor provides that you're looking for. And I don't understand your original business problem well enough to answer that either. Maybe someone else can answer this question in the abstract. Are you familiar with iOS operational queues, dispatch queues, and dispatch sources, as discussed in the Apple [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSOperation *is* roughly equivalent to ThreadPoolExecutor. So you are already using it. If you are exhausting your memory, your concurrency method is probably not the issue.

It sounds like you are building up 300-400 tasks (NSOperations, or GCD blocks) and running out of memory *before* you have them execute. Why not have them execute as you are adding them? That's what NSOperationQueue and GCD queues are *for*, much like ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do but the tasks are created much faster than they are being processed. This means the tasks will go to the NSOperationQueue and wait until they are processed. But there are too many waiting task which leads to the short memory peak which after that leads to the termination of the app.